# App crash in button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have face strange problem on UIButton.

When i tap button the app is crash .

I wrote below code for that...

```
 -(IBAction)renameTest:(id)sender
{

  NSLog(@"Tapped");

    // UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
NSUInteger row = 1;//button.tag;

NSString * titlename = [titleArray objectAtIndex:row];

RenameTest *renameVC = [[RenameTest alloc]initWithNibName:@"RenameTest" bundle:nil];

renameVC.titlespell = titlename;
NSLog(@"titlespell = %@",renameVC.titlespell);

NSLog(@"title = %@",titlename);

    // [button release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:renameVC animated:YES]; //here APP is cresh

[renameVC release];
```

}

I check also my .Xib file name .It is ok and files are there.

error msg is below :

```
   2012-07-11 14:28:29.079 TestApp[238:207] -[__NSCFDictionary _isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x73d8a80
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Wich of the NSLog outputs appear just before you receive the "unrecoginzed selector" error? Does "Tapped" appear at all?

Comment: Yes All NSLog messages are there.

Comment: Have you created the navigation controller?

Comment: Google for isNaturallyRTL. Frankly I do not know what it is about. Apparently it causes crashes now and then. You may find answers in other related questions on stack overflow or in other forums. The message basically says that a message isNaturallyRTL is sent to an object of type NSDictionary which did not implement a method isNaturallyRTS. However, this seesm to be deep in the framwork rather than directly in your code. It may be difficult to determine the root cause. Therefore have a look to those forums on what other programmers expecienced so far.

Comment: What is your `RenameTest` view controller doing in the `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: BTW what is that button, that you are releasing and why? If you release what is not yours and the memory is re-used by other objects and later accessed by some code that assumes that this button still exists, errors like this may occur. So this statment may cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[button release] is causing the problem. Remove it and check.

Comment: I checked it but result was same.

Comment: button creation is right . when i tapped button this IBAction is called and crashed on the push.

Answer (score 0):

_isNaturallyRTL is an NSString method (private), and it looks like you are passing a dictionary instead of a string somewhere.

Breaking on the exception and showing us the call stack at that point would help tremendously.

Comment: I suspect something's fishy in a `viewWillAppear` method somewhere. The call stack will show you which `viewWillAppear` smells the sea.

Answer (score 0):

If u have created the button in xib file then u cannot release it because you have not allocated it and claimed ownership.. U should call release only on objects you have allocated by calling alloc..

Remove the    `[button release]`  statement .. that should fix the crash!

Answer (score 0):

You have a crash which is related to a dictionary and your `titlename` string is set equal to, `titleArray objectAtIndex:row`. 
I believe, without seeing the declaration of your variables, that `titleArray` is a dictionary, or is a `NSMutableArray` importing from a plist of dictionaries, either way you need to use `objectForKey`, when using dictionaries, like this:
`[[titleArray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger *)] objectForKey:(NSString *)]`
Obviously replace `(NSUInteger *)` with your integer `row` and `(NSString *)` with the name of your key. This may not be the answer but from your crash report and visible code, this is what I assume.